# Cannot use the iptables command to create rules for filtering packets [Debian 10]

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, nftables

I'm having an Error while using the `iptables` commands even though I have installed the iptables latest version. The following error shows for the `sudo iptables --list` command,

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.194/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.194
iptables v1.8.2 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

There is no `/lib/modules` directory and `uname -a` shows,

```
Linux vest 4.4.194 #6 SMP Tue Nov 16 17:43:41 CST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

and `lsb_release -a` gives,

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

I have tried to upgrade the kernel and the headers and reboot after upgrading the kernel. Still no luck with the issue. Does anyone know the reason/s for this and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @roaima this is Debian, the kernel says `aarch64` but that’s ARM64, not Arch.

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks. I'd not seen `aarch64` before on either Intel/AMD or the ARM architectures I've got to hand. Poor guess in this case; it looked to me like it was a custom kernel - which could explain the missing `/lib/modules`

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be a custom kernel, or perhaps a BSP kernel for an embedded ARM board.

Comment: @StephenKitt Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @KavinduRathnayaka if your system doesn’t have `/lib/modules`, and you don’t have any other way of getting the appropriate modules, I’m afraid you probably can’t fix this.

Comment: You should install the package `virt-what` and run the command of the same name `virt-what` to double check your current environment which might be in a container rather than bare metal or VM. Your installation has two red herrings: 1/ kernel 4.4 has never been a standard kernel on Debian 2/ missing `/lib/modules`. Whatever the arch Debian provides consistent environment (ok, most of the time anyway). Debian 10 should have provided a kernel 4.19 on x86 armhf aarch64 or whatever. Even Debian 9 comes with kernel 4.9 .